# Custom segue class crashes with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16ecb3ff0)

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to create an app that has a universal background image.  Since most of my ViewController backgrounds are set to clear color,  this presents a problem for most transitions. My solution was to try and create this custom segue class that pushes the source VC to the left and pulls the new VC from the right. However I'm getting this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16ecb3ff0

In interface builder, Storyboard Segue: I have the custom class linked, and set the kind to "Custom". Animates is checked on.  This segue works from my login screen VC to Forgot Password VC but does not work if I use it on my contacts VC to add contact VC.

Not sure why it works on one and not the other? Am I just doing this all wrong? (I'm new to iOS dev and learning)

```
class PushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        push()
    }

    func push () {
        let toViewController = self.destination
        let fromViewController = self.source

        let containerView = fromViewController.view.superview
        let originalCenter = fromViewController.view.center

        fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        fromViewController.view.center = originalCenter

        toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 600, y: 0)
        toViewController.view.center = originalCenter

        containerView?.addSubview(toViewController.view)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform (translationX: -600, y: 0)
        }, completion: {success in
            fromViewController.present(toViewController, animated: false, completion: nil) //Crashes here
        })

    }

}

class UnwindPushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        push()
    }

    func push () {
        let toViewController = self.destination
        let fromViewController = self.source

        fromViewController.view.superview?.insertSubview(toViewController.view, at: 0)
        toViewController.view.superview?.insertSubview(toViewController.view, at: -600)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: { fromViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 600, y: 0)
            toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        }, completion: {success in
            fromViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        })

    }
}
```

I'd expect the source view controller to move to the left, however it does not move left. The new VC comes in from the right but I can still see the source view controller underneath.

Comment: Any error message in Console when it's crashing?

Comment: @Larme  warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.
(lldb).  That error display to the right of "success = (Bool) true _value = (Int) 1